# Should 'openingHours' values be translated?

Tags: date, internationalization, translation, schema.org

From example in [`openingHours`](https://schema.org/openingHours) property, it says

> Days are specified using the following two-letter combinations: Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa, Su.

Shall I assign days by all my supported languages? So if I support Dutch I shall give the schema [Ma, Di, Wo, Do, Vr, Za, Zo] instead?

And how it works? Does Google take the Dutch text from user then searches for schema in the same language? Or translate it to English then searches for English schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are reserved values that should not be translated. You can visually hide these values from your visitors, e.g., because your content is in another language, or because you don’t want to use those abbreviations.

#### JSON-LD

In JSON-LD, the structured data isn’t visible anyway, so you can use any appropriate HTML element to visibly represent the opening hours.

#### Microdata

You can use the `meta` element (uncoupled from the visible content), or the `data` element (coupled to the visible content), or an element like `p` or `span`.

```html
<meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Tu,Th 16:00-20:00" />
<p>dinsdag - donderdag: 16-20 uur</p>
```

```html
<data itemprop="openingHours" value="Tu,Th 16:00-20:00">
  dinsdag - donderdag: 16-20 uur
</data>
```

#### RDFa

You can use the `meta` element (uncoupled from the visible content), or an element like `p` or `span` (coupled to the visible content), but not `data`.

```html
<meta property="openingHours" content="Tu,Th 16:00-20:00" />
<p>dinsdag - donderdag: 16-20 uur</p>
```

```html
<p property="openingHours" content="Tu,Th 16:00-20:00">
  dinsdag - donderdag: 16-20 uur
</p>
```